# Qt QOpenGLFunctions not declared in this scope

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm creating a sort of drawable object class for mesh data and i'm getting this linker error. This is also on top of another class that handles the drawing of the meshes that was used in one of the Qt tutorials. I'm also using a QGLWidget to be the surface i'm drawing to. Here's what the header file looks for the first class.

```
#ifndef GLOBJECT_H
#define GLOBJECT_H
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QVector3D>
#include <QVector2D>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>


struct VertexData
{
    QVector3D position;
    QVector2D texCoord;
    QVector3D normal;
};

class GLObject
{
public:
    GLObject();
    VertexData *data;
    GLushort *indices;
    GLuint vboIds[2];
    int faceCount, vertCount;
    bool generateFromPLY(QString filename);
};

#endif // GLOBJECT_H
```

Here's the header for the other class.

```
#ifndef GEOMETRYENGINE_H
#define GEOMETRYENGINE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QVector2D>
#include <QVector3D>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include <globject.h>

class GeometryEngine : public QObject, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GeometryEngine();
    ~GeometryEngine();

    void init();
    void drawGeometry(QOpenGLShaderProgram *program);
    //void drawCubeGeometry(QOpenGLShaderProgram *program);
    bool generateFromPly(QString filename);
    QVector<GLObject> drawables;
    int drawableId = 0;

};


#endif // GEOMETRYENGINE_H
```

G:\Dropbox\GLSLDemo\globject.cpp:60: error: 'glGenBuffers' was not declared in this scope
  glGenBuffers(2, vboIds);
along with the same error for the other gl calls.
Initially I had all the code in GeometryEngine to begin with. I didn't have a scope issue then. initilizeOpenGLFunctions() is called in GeometryEngine's init() if that's relevant.
                        ^

Comment: That's what QOpenGLFunctions is for though. It introduces a GL/ES 2.0 context to whatever window/widget that inherits it from what I understand. I did have all of this code working but i'm reorganizing it so it isn't such a mess. I could pull up my other working code since I backed it up before breaking too many things. I'm just stumped why it's only now giving me this scope error. Thanks for the header feedback though. I'm still learning how to organize my C projects.

Comment: Not sure what globject.cpp:60 contains, but only GeometryEngine inherits from QOpenGLFunctions (protected), but nothing in globject.h. So I'd assume whatever is in globject.cpp:60, it is it not in the scope of a class inheriting from QOpenGLFunctions

Comment: Oh, so since GeometryEngine inherited with protected, no other class can access those functions? I guess that would make sense. globject.cpp:60 is glBindBuffer() I think. I've actually went ahead and changed things more or less back.

Comment: Yep, for making them publicly available, you'd have to inherit publicly.

Comment: Also, it seems QOpenGLFunctions actually have to be inherited and used as member functions. Well I think I have this mostly sorted out. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

QT OpenGL is weird. I think the QOpenGLFunctions maintains a common context. Also i'm bad at C++ and used protected wrong.